# Set Value Sql Query Result in Input Field From Another Input Field Value (Dynamic Input Field)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, input

I have a problem to display query result in Input field based on value entered by user in another input field. This is dynamic input field (user can add or delete row using javascript). This is my code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    /*
    Javascript Multi Field Dynamic Generator
    */
    var ct = 1;

    // Function Tambah Form
    function new_link()
    {
        ct++;
        var div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.id = ct;

    // Link to Delete Form
    var delLink = '<div style="text-align:left"><a id="del" href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
}
// Function Delete Form
function delIt(eleId)
{
    d = document;

    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);

    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');

    parentEle.removeChild(ele);

}

</script>

<a id="new" href="javascript:new_link()">ADD NEW PAYMENT </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div id="newlink">
    <table id="fit" width="90%">
    <tr bgcolor="#E0ECFF">
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>IDNO</th>
    <th>Bank</th>
    <th>Ket</th>
    <th>text</th>
    <th>text</th>
    <th>option</th>
    <th align="right">Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select name="type[]">
            <?php
            $sql_paytype = mssql_query("...");
            while($rp = mssql_fetch_array($sql_paytype)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo "$rp[Kd_Pay]#$rp[RepCd]";?>"><?php echo $rp[Nm_Pay]?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        // USER ENTER PARAMETER VALUE IDNO TO SELECT AMOUNT FROM TABLE WHERE IDNO = $IDNO
        <input style="width:80px;" type="text" name="idno[]" />
        </td>
         <td>
        <select name="bank[]">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
            $sql_bank = mssql_query("SELECT ...");
            while($rb = mssql_fetch_array($sql_bank)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rb[Kd_Bank]?>"><?php echo "$rb[Kd_Bank] - $rb[Nm_Bank]";?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="width:90px;" type="text" name="ket[]" />
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:90px;" type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
        <td><input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
        <td>
        <select name="option[]">
            <?php
            $sql_curr = mssql_query("SELECT ...");
            while($rc = mssql_fetch_array($sql_curr)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo "$rc[KD_CURR]#$rc[KODE]";?>"><?php echo "$rc[KODE]";?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        // AND THEN QUERY RESULT AMOUNT WILL BE DISPLAYED IN THIS INPUT FIELD
        <input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="amount[]" value="<?php echo $msg?>" onKeyUp="formatNumber(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
 </form>
 </fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>

<!-- Template For Dynamic Multiple Field -->
<div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none" >
<div>
<table id="fit" width="90%">
  <tr>
        <td>
        <select name="type[]">
            <?php
            $sql_paytype = mssql_query("...");
            while($rp = mssql_fetch_array($sql_paytype)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo "$rp[Kd_Pay]#$rp[RepCd]";?>"><?php echo $rp[Nm_Pay]?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="width:80px;" type="text" name="idno[]" />
        </td>
         <td>
        <select name="bank[]">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
            $sql_bank = mssql_query("...");
            while($rb = mssql_fetch_array($sql_bank)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rb[Kd_Bank]?>"><?php echo "$rb[Kd_Bank] - $rb[Nm_Bank]";?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="width:90px;" type="text" name="ket[]" />
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:90px;" type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
        <td><input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
        <td>
        <select name="option[]">
            <?php
            $sql_curr = mssql_query("...");
            while($rc = mssql_fetch_array($sql_curr)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo "$rc[KD_CURR]#$rc[KODE]";?>"><?php echo "$rc[KODE]";?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="amount[]" value="" onKeyUp="formatNumber(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

So, basically **I want input field (name amount[]) will display query result based on input field (idno[]) value that entered by user**..
Please help me to achieve this..

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an ajax call after the user as exited the field idno. This ajax call should have the idn value sent to the server and you server will then be able to query your database en return the required value for your amount field

Answer (score 0):

you have to get idno[] values in some javascript variable or use jquery `$("#idno").val()` send this value using :

```
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:"you php call",
data: $("#idno").val(),
    success : function(data) {// here data is what ever you are returning from method.
// show this received data to your page without page refresh.
}
});
```

Comment: can you show me how to display value to input field amount[] ? I'm stuck in this matter..

Comment: loop through all the data in success and set the values to the inner html of amount[].for this create dynamic amount[0],amount[1]... using javascript method createElement() and use inner html for each amount to write respective data of success to it.

Comment: i'm really confuse about this, but thanks for your reply.. wish anybody out there could give me an example for this case :)

Comment: suppose data in success is an array get the length using data.length then use something like this to display. var  data=[];
data[0] = "XC60";
 data[1] = 'XC60';
 data[2] = "It's alright";


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
data[0] + "<br>" + 
data[1] + "<br>" + 
data[2] + "<br>";
it can help you don.t give id as amount[] to your field but you can use amount[] for name in your fields.

Comment: Hello suchit, i am already make a code but still not working.. I am create new article to post my code.. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544843/show-query-result-into-input-field-based-on-user-input-value-in-dynamic-input-fi Any solution?